# Cannot get manage to properly configure AzureFunction (javascript) with even hub trigger: "No event hub receiver named..."

Tags: javascript, function, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I followed every piece of guideline I could find on how to create a function, in a function app running javascript, that reads events from an event hub. I just cannot make it to accept the configs and connect to the hub to just echo something.

This is my function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "messages",
      "connectionString": "IoTHub_LogItConnectionString",
      "eventHubName": "%IoTHub_LogItEventHubName%",
      "cardinality": "one",
      "dataType": "string",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "eventHubTrigger"
    }
  ]
}
```

this is the error I get:

```
[Error] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.IoTHub_LogIt'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.EventHubs: No event hub receiver named aadc0z0eh-main.
```

If I remove the %% from the eventHubName property value, I just get similar error, but complaining about the receiver called `IoTHub_LogItEventHubName`.

This is the index.js

```
module.exports = function (context, messages) {
    context.log(`JavaScript eventhub trigger function called for message array: ${messages}`);
    
    messages.forEach(message => {
        context.log(`Processed message: ${message}`);
    });

    context.done();
};
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Do you test it on local? Have you set the `IoTHub_LogItEventHubName` in the local.settings.json?

Comment: It is on PoC stage right now. I would expect it to out-of-the-box in the Portal. So no, I did not test it locally, only playing with the Portal. And yes, I dit set the two properties `IoTHub_LogItConnectionString` and `IoTHub_LogItEventHubName` in the FunctionApp configuration

Comment: Just to confirm, the connection string that you're using is to an Event Hubs namespace, not to an IoT Hub and not an Event Hub-level connection string?

Comment: I tried every possible combination, connection string from the hub namespace, from the hub itself, nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I deleted the function app, recreated it, and added the function again BUT using the option: any editor and function tool.

Worked with both version 2 and 3 of the function tool. I only changed the version (2 or 3) or node used (10 or 12) in the function app settings.

I was able to test it locally and with the real function.

What I think was the difference was that I had to also create a storage account and provide the connection string for it. (prop name AzureWebJobsStorage in the function app settings and also in local.settings.json so that it works locally)